# How to add autoreload to gulpfile for gulp sass compiler?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I want to increase my productivity with gulp sass, therefore I want to use autoreload to simply reload my page when I changed something in my sass file, the problem is that I didnt found a proper solution. Do someone know how this works?

My gulpfile that I've written is here:

```html
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
 return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
 .pipe(sass())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is numerous ways to get auto-reload functionality, example below uses [gulp-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect). I've also keep several other useful pieces of SCSS compilation flow into this example, comments are added to let you get an idea.

```
"use strict";

var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var gulp = require("gulp");
var connect = require("gulp-connect");
var plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
var postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task('server', function () {
    connect.server({    // Create local server that will auto-reload itself upon changes into project
        root: '.',      // Path to WEB root (NOT simply root!) of your project
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
        return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')   // Notice changed glob, it will allow you to compile scss files that are resides into deeper directories
            .pipe(plumber())    // Plumber is useful to avoid crashing Gulp in a case if plugin throws exception
            .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))  // Make sure that errors are logged
            .pipe(postcss([     // PostCSS plugins run, Autoprefixer in particular
                autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE >= 11', '> 1%']})
            ]))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))     // Save resulted CSS
            .pipe(connect.reload());    // Re-load browser so changes will became visible
    }
);

gulp.task('default', ['css']);  // Compile CSS by default

gulp.task('watch', ['server', 'default'], function () {     // Make sure that server is launched in a case if we're running watching
    gulp.watch([
        './sass/**/*.scss'
    ], ['css']);
});
```

After setting up local server you will be able to reach your project through `localhost:8080` by running `gulp watch` or `gulp server`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`browserSync`](https://browsersync.io/). It's a highly configurable local server with live reload capabilities. [It's a nice match for `gulp`](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp).

After running `gulp default`, you can access your site at http://localhost:3000

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Init browserSync
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./",
            directory: true
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
    // Stream changes to browserSync to live reload CSS changes
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass'])
});

// Add browserSync-init to default task
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch', 'browser-sync']);
```